# Strange header ("b8") in node-static web server page

Tags: html, node.js, web-hosting

I am trying to create a very basic static web server that records the IP addresses of each client machine served.

By and large, it is working... but the web site as served has a strange header... b8:

[image: screenshot]

This header doesn't show up in my html at all, and I'm rather confused.

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Science Treasure Hunt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Eventual Home of Science Treasure Hunt Webpage</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My guess is that it is somewhere on the node.js side of things, but I don't know what could be causing it from that end, either...

index.js code:

```
let http = require('http');
let requestIp = require('request-ip');
let winston = require('winston');
let static = require('node-static');

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80);

let logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.printf(info => {
            return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
        })
    ),
    transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({filename: 'firstlog.log'})
    ]
});

var file = new(static.Server)('./public');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    file.serve(request, response);
    var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;
    logger.log('info', ip);
    response.writeHead(200);
}
```

What might be happening here?

Comment: html in developer tools looks different from the index.html that you have shared. title tag in dev tools is in body while in index.html its inside head. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file?

Comment: Well, it is definitely the right file, as I wrote it. It may not be coded correctly... but it is the file that the index.js code is trying to serve up.